# How to create 2 columns, incrementally, together in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given for example

```
a  b       c
1 nan    nan
2 nan    nan
3 nan    nan
4 nan    nan
```

(Or with no columns b and c)

I want to create columns b and c such that every row depends on the previous row in a custom way.

For this example, the dependency will be (b depends on a and c, and c depends on a and b)
In pseudocode:

```
def foo(row, default=1):
    Return row["a"] or default + 2* row["c"] or default, row["a"] or default + row["b"] or default
```

Meaning, the stopping condition for every column is 1, and if values exist, then use them as follows, recursively:

`Next b = prev a + 2* prev c`

`Next c = prev a + prev b`

The result would be

```
a  b       c
1  3       2
2  5       4
3  10      7
4  17      13
```

I thought `rolling` should have something similar, but have no idea how to use it for this use case.

I hope I made my intention clear, even if the syntax is lacking.

---

Please notice I am looking for a pandas solution, looping over the dataframe myself it obvious.

Comment: How did you get the values for column b = 3 and column c= 2 for the first row? is it to be provided upfront?

Comment: @SarunDahal they were derived by default=1. I would assume such recursive operations should be able to take in the stopping criteria

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ mistake fixed, see edit please.

Comment: @AndrejKesely please see edit. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values for column b = 3 and column c= 2 for the very first row is provided by the user, the final output can be achieved as follow:

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5]
b= [3] + [0] * (len(a) - 1)
c= [2] + [0] * (len(a) - 1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})

index= 0
while index < (len(df)-1):
    
    #the default values for elements of subsequent row being 1 (as per question), 
    v1= max(1, df.at[index, 'a'] + 2* df.at[index, 'c'])
    v2= max(1, df.at[index, 'a'] + df.at[index, 'b'])
    
    l2= [a[index+1]]
    l2.extend((v1, v2))
    
    #changing the subsequent row for dataframe df
    df.loc[index + 1] = l2
    index+=1

print(df)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for pure pandas solution, with no Python loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Please notice I am looking for a pandas solution.

There is no gain in speed using Pandas as iterative calculations are not easily vectorizable.

```
def compute_next(row):
  prev_a, prev_b, prev_c = row
  a = prev_a + 1
  b = prev_a + 2 * prev_c
  c = prev_a + prev_b
  return a, b, c

data = [[1, 3, 2]]

for i in range(10):
  data.append(compute_next(data[i]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: I'd expect for some function that allows "cumsum" calculations (for general functions), with some backend in c. Guess it is too much. `numba` to the rescue?